# Address return by new operator in C++

Tags: c++

Address returned by new operator in C++ is unique throughout the process?
What if someone delete the memory, can same address be returned by new again?

Best Regards,
Chandan

Comment: Where did you get that info? What else have you found there? This sounds a lot like homework, so it would be customary to demonstrate your own efforts first.

Comment: Did you try it ? https://godbolt.org/z/o3Yoz9Y86

Comment: In fact, I once ran into an issue due to the fact that memory had been re-used after `delete` for a `new` of something else. I had cached pointers which magically became "valid" again but where pointing to something else now. The internal heap management probably tries to re-use same blocks for classes of same size (due to internal organization in buckets). This made the effect even more confusing and I needed a while until I understood my mistake...

Comment: If you want to use memory addresses as keys (e.g. in a map), you should make sure that you do not create a new instance after deleting another one. If you describe your requirements (e.g. no memory overhead for additional key member variable), we might suggest an alternative.

Comment: You're either misunderstanding your source, or your source has no understanding.

Comment: According to the standard, if a program uses a pointer after a valid `delete` expression on that pointer, the program behaviour is undefined. Nothing is said about whether that pointed-to memory is reused, or what happens if that `delete`d pointer is compared with another pointer (whether returned by a subsequent `new` expression or not). When behaviour is undefined by the standard, the implementation is free to do what it likes - testing equality of the `delete`d pointer with any other pointer can give a `true` result, a `false` result, or it can crash your program - any outcome is permitted.

Comment: Memory addresses get reused (or you would run out).  Often sub-allocators are used rather than going to the kernel for a new block of memory for every request (also the kernel can only allocate memory in pages typically 4k which is excessive if you only asked for 10 bytes).  Freed  memory is return to the sub-allocator pool which is used for new requests before the memory sub-allocator has to ask the kernel for more memory.

Comment: An implementation could on `delete` change the contents of some or all of the pointers to the deleted memory or make them invalid. E.g. if you run C++ in a super-safe environment, which prevents use-after-free by this and sacrifices performance.

Answer (score 2):

The return value of `new` is not guaranteed to be unique throughout your processes' runtime. The only real guarantees you get are that the value is non-null, aligned to the requested type, and is at least large enough to fit the requested type (or, you get a `std::bad_alloc`). You can likely observe this on your own system with the following snippet:

```cpp
int main()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
    int *p = new int;
    std::cout << reinterpret_cast<void *>(p) << std::endl;
    delete p;
  }
}

/*
  Example output:
  0x2576e70
  0x2576e70
  ...
*/
```

Of course, an implementation *may* opt to give you unique addresses every time. However, I suspect no common implementation would provide this by default.

Answer (score 0):

C++ standard guarantees comparison and pointer arithmetics of two pointers to be correct only if both pointers refer to locations in storage of *same object* or to elements of same array. If the old object was deleted and new was created in such way that pointer refers to a memory location in its storage, the result of comparison is undefined as well as result of dereferencing such pointer.

1. You had created an object `A` of type `T` and a pointer to it `T* pA`.

Possible  follow ups:

2. You destroyed `A` by calling `delete pA`. Value of pA didn't change.
3. You had created an object `B` of type `T` and a pointer to it `B* pB`.
4. You compare pA which contains address in storage of defunct object A and pB which contains address in storage of object B.
5. Result of comparison is (undefined) true, because memory was re-used, or
6. Result of comparison is (undefined) false, because {implementation defined reasons}.

But another way  if may fail on some platforms where paged memory is swapped out.

2. You had created an object `B` of type `T` and a pointer to it `B* pB`.
3. You compare `pA` which contains address in storage of still existing object `A` and `pB` which contains address in storage of object `B`.
4. Result of comparison is (undefined) true, because memory was swapped, or
5. Result of comparison is (undefined) false, because objects aren't in concurrent page or are in same page.

For that reason, compilers on systems with such possibility implement a pointer as a structure with additional information, not as mere address, to track where objects are currently stored.

There is no guarantees that the value of a correct pointer to dynamically or automatically created storage would be unique or not. The nature of computer's architecture suggests that memory would be reused as you have limited resources.

PS. You still can use pointers to identify separate objects if they are elements of same array, including case where they were created by placement-new in same array. It's a valid strategy for a memory pool, but creations and deletion of objects have to be tracked somehow to identify if a particular object is still "alive".